# Is it possible to put an if condition inside of a listValue of a <s:select> tag?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I have the following `s:select` tag on my jsp page:

```
 <s:select name="collaborator" listValue="%{title.designation+' '+name}" value="cololaborator" id="collaborator" listKey="id"  list="listaPsmPse" ></s:select>
```

I wanna know if it is possible to do something like this:

```
listValue="if(title!=null)%{title.designation+' '+name}else%{name}"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write it using [`ternary if`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/?%3a) like so:

```
listValue="title !=null ? title.designation + ' ' + name : name"
```

Answer (score 0):

The tag says you are using struts. I recommend using a bean. In the struts Action handler, calculate the value that you want to show for the listValue. Set that value in a bean property and use the value of the bean property as your listValue. So the actual calculation should be done in the Java code (struts), not in the JSP itself. That would be the best way I think.

For an example of what I am talking about please see the accepted answer written by Buhake Sindi for the following StackOverflow question:

[how to use <bean:write > tag in strut 1.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6692995/how-to-use-beanwrite-tag-in-strut-1-2)

Comment: if anyone can explain to me how to link directly to the answer that would be appreciated...

Comment: I was hope there was a more direct way, but I'll see that post and try to do it.. thanks

Comment: @dabasiu You can embed scriptlets into JSP but it's something I consider a bad practice, and I don't even know how to do it off the top of my head. But it can be done.

Comment: However everything *in* the question is Struts 2, thus useless. Every answer has a "share" link that shows the answer's link.